# What agency in Serbia enforces passenger compensation rights?

Tags: air-travel, compensation, serbia

Air Serbia cancelled a flight from Belgrade to Vienna, but now refuses to pay either meal/accommodation expenses or compensation, despite already having promised in writing and over the phone to pay expenses. We appealed to the [Agency for Passenger Rights](https://www.apf.gv.at/en/), Austria's national enforcement agency for passenger compensation claims, but they replied that the matter is out of their jurisdiction.  (Flights *into* the EU on non-EU carriers are generally not covered by [EU Regulation 261/2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation).)

However, Air Serbia maintains its own [statement of passenger rights](https://www.airserbia.com/en/footer_copy_menu/legal/passenger_rights/notice)<sup>*</sup> and also mentions that these rights are prescribed by Serbian law, so we may still be able to pursue the matter in Serbia.  **What government agency is responsible for enforcing passenger compensation rights in Serbia, and how can we contact them to lodge a complaint?**  If there is no such government agency, is there a private claims processor that we can use?  (There are a lot of such processors in the EU, such as [ClaimCompass](https://www.claimcompass.eu/en/), but all the ones we checked deal only with claims covered by the EU regulations, not the Serbian ones.)

---

<sup>*</sup> Note that due to Air Serbia's broken website, you may need to follow that link twice before the correct page appears.  It seems that first-time visitors to the website are always redirected to its home page.

---

**UPDATE:** In case anyone is interested, on 19 April 2020 we submitted our claim by e-mail to the Civil Aviation Directorate of the Republic of Serbia, as suggested in [the answer by Crazydre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/156745/7949).  By 6 May 2020 we had not received a response, so on that day we sent a copy of the complaint via registered post.  It's been over three months since the initial submission, and we still haven't had any response from the Directorate.

Comment: Get a SIM card with cheap rates to Serbia and call them, quoting your case number if there is any

Comment: @Crazydre: Are they likely to speak to us in English (or Russian or German)? We don't speak Serbo-Croatian (though if absolutely necessary, we have a Serbian neighbour we might call upon for a favour).

Comment: They do have employees who speak English. If the one you get doesn't, you should be transferred

Comment: BTW the phone number is +381 11 292 70 00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be the Civil Aviation Directorate of the Republic of Serbia.

Print [this form](http://cad.gov.rs/upload/putnici/Prava%20putnika%20-%20obrazac%20za%20podnosenje%20reklamacije.pdf), fill it in, sign it and scan it in. Then send it, along with all other evidence, to reklamacijeputnika@cad.gov.rs

As I said before, you're probably **not** entitled to compensation, but **are** eligible for reimbursement of additional expenses. Especially mention the fact that Air Serbia had agreed to it on the phone, before changing their minds.